# Check if entry to panda dataframe is unique when index might be the same

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda DataFrame that I want to add rows to. The Dataframe looks like this:

```
   col1  col2
a     1     5
b     2     6
c     3     7
```

I want to add rows to the dataframe, but only if they are unique. The problem is that some new rows might have the same index, but different values in the columns. If this is the case, I somehow need to know.

Some example rows to be added and the desired result:

row 1:

```
   col1  col2
a     1     5
```

desired row 1 result: Not added - it is already in the dataframe

row 2:

```
   col1  col2
a     9     9
```

desired row 2 result: something like,

```
print('non-unique entries for index a')
```

row 3:

```
   col1  col2
d     4     4
```

desired row 3 result: just add the row to the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
# existing dataframe == df
# new rows == df_newrows

# dividing newrows dataframe into two, one for repeated indexes, one without.

df_newrows_usable = df_newrows.loc[df_newrows.index.isin(list(df.index.get_values()))==False]
df_newrows_discarded = df_newrows.loc[df_newrows.index.isin(list(df.index.get_values()))]

print ('repeated indexes:', df_newrows_discarded)

# concat df and newrows without repeated indexes

new_df = pd.concat([df,df_newrows],0)

print ('new dataframe:', new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy option would be to merge all rows and then keep the unique ones via the dataframe method [drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

However, this option doesn't report a warning / error when a duplicate row is appended.

drop_duplicates doesn't consider indexes, so the dataframe must be reset before dropping the duplicates, and set back after:

```
import pandas as pd
# set up data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2':[5, 6, 7]}, index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
# set up row to be appended
row = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[3], 'col2': [7]}, index=['c'])
# append row (don't care if it's duplicate)
df = df.append([row])
# drop duplicatesdf2 = df2.reset_index()
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates()
df2 = df2.set_index('index')
```

if the warning message is an absolute requirement, we can write a function to that effect that checks if a row is duplicate via a merge operation and appends the row only if it is unique.

```
def append_unique(df, row):
    d = df.reset_index()
    r = row.reset_index()
    if d.merge(r, on=list(d.columns), how='inner').empty:
        d2 = d.append(r)
        d2 = d2.set_index('index')
        return d2
    print('non-unique entries for index a')
    return df

df2 = append_unique(df2, row)
```